# Fastest generated BMP to URL encoding - how to?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, url, binary

How I can much faster encode BMP to URL?

Here is full code. 
https://github.com/acterhd/bmpgen/blob/gh-pages/bmpgen.js

Comment: That function will fail for Unicode characters outside the first two code blocks.